# UWP VisualStateManager.GotoState works not correctly

Tags: c#, uwp, visualstatemanager

I have a custom control `MediaPlayerControl`. In the its Template I define a `VisualStateGroup`:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="SizeState">
    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
    <VisualState x:Name="LargeSize" >
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MediaInfo_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.ColumnSpan)" >
                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MediaInfo_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RowSpan)" >
                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2"/>
             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PrimaryMediaControl_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="HorizontalAlignment" >
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Center"/>
             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MediaTransportControls_Timeline_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)" >
                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MediaTransportControls_Timeline_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.ColumnSpan)" >
                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MoreButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SecondaryTrim_MenuFlyOut" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TrimButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
         </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

And in the `SizeChanged` event I call `ChangeState()` function:

```
private void MediaPlayerControl_SizeChanged(object sender, object e)
{
    ChangeState();
}
private void ChangeState()
{
    string state = "";
    if (Window.Current.Bounds.Width < 600)
    {
        state = "Normal";
    }
    else
    {
        state = "LargeSize";
    }
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, state, false);
}
```

Although `VisualStateManager.GoToState` return `true` and UI change to `LargeSize` state but in short time it automatically changes to `Normal` state.

If I use `LayoutUpdated` event, it work properly, but performance is not good.

Can I use `GotoState` with `SizeChanged` event?

Comment: I would guess that there are some other trigger which makes your UI go back to normal state but I have no idea what it is. Can you provide more details about your project, like a demo or share us the steps about how we can reproduce this issue?